# Chainlink Automation: why is registering upkeep directly from contract reverting?

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-automation

I have a factory contract which deploys a custom contract. The custom contract imports `Automation Compatible.sol` and implements `checkUpkeep()` and `performUpkeep()`

The factory contract has a function for creating a new custom contract. When a new custom contract is created, the same function calls the following function, passing the new contract as a parameter, to register it.

```
function registerUpkeepForDeployedContract(address _deployedContract) private returns (bool) {
        bytes memory registrationData =
            abi.encode("", hex"", _deployedContract, 200000, owner(), 0, hex"", hex"", hex"", 1000000000000000000);

        LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(registrar, 1000000000000000000);
        bool success = LinkTokenInterface(link).transferAndCall(registrar, 1000000000000000000, registrationData);
        if (!success) revert DerivativeFactory__LinkTransferAndCallFailed();
        return success;
    }
```

`link` and `registrar` are set in the constructor with the relevant testnet's addresses. I send LINK tokens to the factory contract before attempting to create and register a new custom contract, but the transaction reverts everytime. The revert is happening because of the `registerUpkeepForDeployedContract()` shared above, versions of the same factory contract without Automation registration have worked fine.

If anyone can offer any help I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

*Edit:*
I tried a slightly different way based on [this example from the Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/guides/register-upkeep-in-contract#upkeep-registration-parameters-and-examples), but it still reverts. Here is what I did:

I defined these outside the contract:

```
struct RegistrationParams {
    string name;
    bytes encryptedEmail;
    address upkeepContract;
    uint32 gasLimit;
    address adminAddress;
    uint8 triggerType;
    bytes checkData;
    bytes triggerConfig;
    bytes offchainConfig;
    uint96 amount;
}

interface AutomationRegistrarInterface {
    function registerUpkeep(RegistrationParams calldata requestParams) external returns (uint256);
}
```

and added this function to be called when a new Automation Compatible contract is created, passing its address as a parameter:

```
function registerAndPredictID(address _deployedContract) public {
        RegistrationParams memory params = RegistrationParams({
            name: "",
            encryptedEmail: hex"",
            upkeepContract: _deployedContract,
            gasLimit: 2000000,
            adminAddress: owner(),
            triggerType: 0,
            checkData: hex"",
            triggerConfig: hex"",
            offchainConfig: hex"",
            amount: 1000000000000000000
        });

        LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(registrar, params.amount);
        uint256 upkeepID = AutomationRegistrarInterface(registrar).registerUpkeep(params);
        if (upkeepID != 0) {
            emit UpkeepRegistered(upkeepID, _deployedContract);
        } else {
            revert("auto-approve disabled or registration failed");
        }
    }
```

*Edit:*
I put together a basic test contract with the above premise and Automation Compatible to try out in Remix - it is still reverting after sending it LINK and trying to call `registerAndPredictID()` with its own address:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {LinkTokenInterface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {AutomationCompatible} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/AutomationCompatible.sol";

struct RegistrationParams {
    string name;
    bytes encryptedEmail;
    address upkeepContract;
    uint32 gasLimit;
    address adminAddress;
    uint8 triggerType;
    bytes checkData;
    bytes triggerConfig;
    bytes offchainConfig;
    uint96 amount;
}

interface AutomationRegistrarInterface {
    function registerUpkeep(RegistrationParams calldata requestParams) external returns (uint256);
}

contract AutoTest is Ownable, AutomationCompatible {
    error NoLinkToWithdraw();
    error LinkTransferFailed();

    event UpkeepRegistered(uint256 upkeepID, address derivativeContract);

    address public link;
    address public registrar;

    constructor(address _link, address _registrar) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        link = _link;
        registrar = _registrar;
    }

    function registerAndPredictID(address _deployedContract) public {
        RegistrationParams memory params = RegistrationParams({
            name: "",
            encryptedEmail: '0x',
            upkeepContract: _deployedContract,
            gasLimit: 2000000,
            adminAddress: msg.sender,
            triggerType: 0,
            checkData: '0x',
            triggerConfig: '0x',
            offchainConfig: "",
            amount: 5000000000000000000
        });

        LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(registrar, params.amount);
        uint256 upkeepID = AutomationRegistrarInterface(registrar).registerUpkeep(params);
        if (upkeepID != 0) {
            emit UpkeepRegistered(upkeepID, _deployedContract);
        } else {
            revert("auto-approve disabled or registration failed");
        }
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */ )
        external
        view
        cannotExecute
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */ )
    {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp >= block.timestamp + 10 minutes);
        return (upkeepNeeded, bytes(""));
    }

  
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */ ) external {
        
    }

    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 balance = LinkTokenInterface(link).balanceOf(address(this));
        if (balance == 0) revert NoLinkToWithdraw();

        if (!LinkTokenInterface(link).transfer(msg.sender, balance)) revert LinkTransferFailed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this with someone from Chainlink, it turned out the registrar address in the docs was out of date. I'm happy to have helped find this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello [palmcivet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/120895/palmcivet)

The docs are being updated, but if you are on one of these networks, please use these updated addresses:

- Eth Sepolia Registrar: 0xb0E49c5D0d05cbc241d68c05BC5BA1d1B7B72976
- Polygon Registrar: 0x0Bc5EDC7219D272d9dEDd919CE2b4726129AC02B
- Arb Goerli Registry: 0x3202a5e8f50f31a89a785eE096468DB338E93DF3
- Opt Goerli Registrar: 0xCA7A0b1F8153EcD3861899d468dC946F22B39114